Generated library does not work when integrating with other applications
I just developed a library with React.
The goal of this library is that it will be functional on all types of React and no-React applications.
Currently, I encountered a problem while testing my lib on other applications.
The problem that the generated code does not find React knowing that I have indicated that React and React-dom are external libs in my vite.config.ts file
Thank you for guiding me to resolve this problem. the objective is for the generated code to be completely autonomous and independent
Below you will find the contents of my files:

vite.config.ts file

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react()
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.tsx'),
      name: 'accessibility-turnkey',
      formats: ['es', 'umd'],
      fileName: (format) => `accessibility-turnkey.${format}.js`,
    }, 
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },
    emptyOutDir: true,
  }
})


and package.json file

{
  "name": "accessibility-turnkey",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/accessibility-turnkey.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/accessibility-turnkey.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/accessibility-turnkey.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/accessibility-turnkey.umd.js"
    },
    "./style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "./dist/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": { ... },
  "devDependencies": { ... }
}


This is the error encountered with .es.js version
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

with .umd.js version
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED')


A bit late of a reply, but have you tried exporting global definitions for your externals?
For just UMD it would be something like this:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react()
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.tsx'),
      name: 'accessibility-turnkey',
      formats: ['es', 'umd'],
      fileName: (format) => `accessibility-turnkey.${format}.js`,
    }, 
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      globals: {
        'react': 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        'react-dom/client': 'ReactDOM',
      }
    },
    emptyOutDir: true,
  }
})

For both ESM and UMD you can switch out the 'globals'-object in the rollupOptions and use a plugin like this:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'
import externalGlobals from 'rollup-plugin-external-globals';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react()
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.tsx'),
      name: 'accessibility-turnkey',
      formats: ['es', 'umd'],
      fileName: (format) => `accessibility-turnkey.${format}.js`,
    }, 
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      plugins: [
        externalGlobals({
          'react': 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          'react-dom/client': 'ReactDOM',
        })
      ].filter(Boolean),
    },
    emptyOutDir: true,
  }
})

